# Stuck in asnyc/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Searched on many places and also went through many tutorials to deeply understand the async/awiat behavior of the javascript. Here is my code:

```
var bookAppointment =  async (data) => {
    return User.findOne({_id: data.user_id})
    .then((userfound) =>{
            //manipulate user's data and find if in array the specific object exist
            var found = await userfound.dataArray.find( function(element){
              return element.data == data.user_data
            });
            //here I want to wait until above result comes to evaulate below condition
            if(found)
            {
                return "Sorry! data does not exist";
            }
            else
            {
                return userfound;
            }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err 
    });
}
```

What I want to achieve is to make my if else condition to wait above find function on array of javascript. Here is the error I'm facing:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I'm unable to understand where I'm wrong! Even my function has keyword async with its definition. Anyone around for a quick help?

Comment: at `(userfound) =>{...}` you're scoping another function, for await to work, you need it to be something like `async (userfound) => {...}`

Comment: the entire piece inside `(userfound) => {...}` is going to be run in sync , one step at a time, why do you want to wait for a `.find` method? . If you do wanna wait , follow comment above.

Comment: Works like a charm! Haha Thank you so much!! Wasted almost 2 hours on my foolish mistake!! Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `(userfound) =>{...}` you're scoping another function.

For await to work, you need it to be something like `async (userfound) => {...}`

Comment: Thanks dude for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

Catch and Then keyword are not used is async/await functions.

```
    var bookAppointment = async (data) => {
      var found = await User.findOne({_id: data.user_id});
      try {
      //do here like in then
      } catch (e) {
      //error handling
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong in several ways.  First off, the try/catch has to have the `await User.findOne()` inside the `try` block to do any good.  And, you can use `.then()` in combination with `await` if you want.  It would work fine.